# C# Method run time increases the more it is called

Tags: c#, linq, methods

I am running into a very strange issue where the execution time of a method seems to increase the more it is called.

Here is my method that checks to see if a records needs to be updated.

```
public override bool NeedsUpdate(object obj)
{
    BizContact contact = obj as BizContact;

    int id = contact.ID;

    DataRow contactRow = dbRows.FirstOrDefault(dr =>(int)dr[keyMapping.ColumnName]) == contact.ID);
    if (contactRow == null)
        return false;

    DateTime localLastModified = (DateTime)contactRow["LastModified"];

    return contact.LastModified > localLastModified;

}
```

The dbRows collection is a List with a size that doesn't increase after the first time NeedsUpdate gets called.

There are lots of records to check so NeedsUpdate gets called thousands of times in a loop.

The first time it gets called it takes well under 1 millisecond to run.

After 1,000 calls the method is taking 64 milliseconds to complete.

After 2,000 calls the method is taking 138 milliseconds to complete.

After 3,000 calls the method is taking 187 milliseconds to complete.

The dbRows collection has 28,000 records so I know lookup time will take a while but I would at least expect it to be consistent.

Any idea what I might be missing?

This is how it is used:

```
foreach (object obj in dataWrapper.GetObjects())
{
    // OTHER CODE

    Stopwatch checkUpdateSW = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    bool needsUpdate = dataWrapper.NeedsUpdate(obj);
    checkUpdateSW.Stop();

    // OTHER CODE
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the time is being spent in `NeedsUpdate`?  If you're using DataContext or EntityFramework to modify records, there are known issues as you modify more and more entities, and the number tracked increases in a single context, you can see reduced performance.

Comment: That's linear, and it is expected to increase with increase in no.of columns, what is strange behavior ?

Comment: Do you happen to have your records to check in the same order as the queries? What is the type of `dbRows`? Could you make it a `Dictionary`?

Comment: @HariPrasad There is no increase in number of columns. This isn't total time spent running the method. It is the take taken to execute the method a single time. Also, this isn't querying a database. The dbRows variable is an in memory List of DataRow objects.

Comment: @James How do you call this code? Can you include that piece in question?

Comment: @James Do you know if it's because of many executions or because of each object? Can you run the loop in reverse and tell us the results?

Comment: @moreON I can't really run in reverse with out a lot of change but each object is very similar. I'm just using the ID.

Comment: @James foreach(var o in Enumerable.Reverse()) ... ? Or are the other operations in the loop dependant on the processing order? ... I have a suspicion that the increased processing time is due to you producing things that are encountered earlier while enumerating dbRows, in your earlier calls. Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(cond) has to process each element sequentially until it finds one that matches. If an element is later, it takes longer to find. Running in reverse would help confirm or reject this hypothesis easily.

Comment: @moreON the enumeration of the foreach (dataWrapper.GetObjects) is using a yield return so I'm not sure sure reversing it would work without other change.

Comment: @James That's still an IEnumerable. Reverse() would (I think, not certain on implementation) simply enumerate all the way through, storing each result in a list, then iterate backward through that list, yielding each element. Generally, linq just works (except when you forget about deferred execution).

Answer (score 2):

One case where linear search is actually faster than you'd expect is if items you are looking for are in the beginning of large list.

So possible explanation - you are searching for records that are farther from the beginning with each call. Sample with basic list:

```
 var list = Enumerable.Range(1,10000).ToList();

 for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
 {
     // this linear search call will be very fast first and gradually 
     // slow down toward the end
     var r = list.FirstOrDefaut(i);
 }
```